# DynamoDB update entire column efficiently

Tags: database, python-2.7, amazon-dynamodb, insert-update

I have a dynamo table called 'Table'. There are a few columns in the table, including one called 'updated'. I want to set all the 'updated' field to '0' without having to providing a key to avoid fetch and search in the table.

I tried batch write, but seems like update_item required Key inputs. How could I update the entire column to have every value as 0 efficiently please?

I am using a python script.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this point, you **cannot** do this, we have to pass a key (Partition key or Partition key and sort key) to update the item.

Currently, the only way to do this is to scan the table with filters to get all the values which have 0 in "updated" column and get respective Keys.

Pass those keys and update the value.

Hopefully, in future AWS will come up with something better.

Answer (score 0):

If you can get partition key, for each partition key you can update the item